# Covert response from XML to JSON

Tags: java, json, xml

I have made a small program for testing to convert xml to json.
As

```
public class XmlTester {
    private static final String XML_TEXT = "<note>\n" + "<to>Tove</to>\n" + "<from>Jani</from>\n"
            + "<heading>Reminder</heading>\n" + "<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>\n" + "</note>";
    private static final int i = 4;

    public void convert() {
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(XML_TEXT);
        String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(i);
        System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
    }
}
```

But the problem is I am not able to import org.json.XML.Although able to import org.json.jsonobject.
so is this the problem of dependency?

Answer (score 0):

**Add this below dependency ,**

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
```

**Jar** [java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm](http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm)

*OR*

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20131018</version>
</dependency>
```

**Here is the code**

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Test {

    private static final String XML_TEXT = "<note>\n" + "<to>Tove</to>\n" + "<from>Jani</from>\n"
            + "<heading>Reminder</heading>\n" + "<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>\n" + "</note>";
    private static final int i = 4;

    public static void convert() {
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(XML_TEXT);
        String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(i);
        System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        convert();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{"note": {
    "heading": "Reminder",
    "from": "Jani",
    "to": "Tove",
    "body": "Don't forget me this weekend!"
}}
```

Comment: not able to import import org.json.XML;
could you help me?

Comment: you use maven ?

Comment: if you use jar then import this jar file , http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm

Comment: yeah..its maven

Answer (score 0):

The program runs fine, the only point missing is that you haven't added the following jar:

```
java-json.jar
```

The program that you've posted, I was able to run it just fine:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class XMLtoJSON {
    private static final String XML_TEXT = "<note>\n" + "<to>Tove</to>\n" + "<from>Jani</from>\n"
            + "<heading>Reminder</heading>\n" + "<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>\n" + "</note>";
    private static final int i = 4;

    public static void convert() {
        JSONObject xmlJSONObj;
        String jsonPrettyPrintString = null;
        try {
            xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(XML_TEXT);
            jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        convert();
    }
}
```

Output of the program is as expected:

```
{"note": {
    "heading": "Reminder",
    "from": "Jani",
    "to": "Tove",
    "body": "Don't forget me this weekend!"
}}
```

Maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: For Maven, you'll need to add the Maven dependencies.

Comment: Yeah Sam, Updated my answer with the dependency details for you to use!

Comment: You're welcome - If this answer helped you, please accept it!